# Rewrite last modified date when unzipping archive

Tags: files, osx, date, zip

Is there a way to rewrite the last modified date of all the files inside a .zip file to the date of extraction?

Basically, whenever someone unzips the archive, the `last modified date` of all files is changed to the date of the zip extraction?

Comment: To reword (and double-check): you want the *extracted* filenames to have a current timestamp and not the one that zip reassigns? Or do you want to re-date files that are inside of a zip file?

Comment: do you want to re-date files that are inside of a zip file?

Answer (score 6):

With libarchive `bsdtar` ([supports all sorts of archive formats](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/wiki/LibarchiveFormats), including pkzip's), use the `m` flag:

```
bsdtar xmf file.zip
```

From the [manual](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/wiki/ManPageBsdtar1):

> `-m`, `--modification-time`
>                (x mode only) Do not extract modification time.  By default, the modification time is set to the time stored in the archive.

Note that the `m` flag is not specific to `bsdtar`, it was already there in [the first implementation of `tar` in Unix V7 in 1979](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tar&manpath=Unix%20Seventh%20Edition). What is specific to `bsdtar` is the support for archive formats other than `tar`.

With `unzip`, see the `-DD` option.

Comment: Both options worked out for me! I just have one question. Whenever I use `bsdtar xmf file.zip` or `unzip -DD file.zip` a new `__MACOSX` folder is created. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @Johnny That has nothing to do with the question at hand. The directory is likely part of the archive, and if you don't need its contents you could probably just follow up with a `rm -r __MACOSX` after extraction.

Comment: Answer comments are not for asking questions.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/510704/5132 is how one asks a question.