# How do I prevent a __MACOSX from being created when I extract an archive that I created on MacOS?

Tags: osx, tar, zip

From commentary in "[Rewrite last modified date when unzipping archive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/510690/5132)":

I have a ZIP archive that I created on MacOS.
Whenever I use

```
bsdtar xmf file.zip
```

or

```
unzip -DD file.zip
```

to extract it a new `__MACOSX` folder is created. Is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

For Info-ZIP's `unzip` this is a simple exercise in the use of the `-x` option to exclude files by name.  Witness https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/269808/5132 for example, where Gilles used:

```
unzip -x __MACOSX -x '__MACOSX/*' /path/to/zip
```

This of course needs combining with your `-DD` option.  Obviously.

With `bsdtar` there is a similar `--exclude` option.

Note that the preferred usage form for `bsdtar` has *always* been getopt-style options, since [its invention](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/2588e5ad7af384b20a9acae84814c857640b02df/usr.bin/tar/bsdtar.c#L162), and one should endeavour not to acquire the habit in the first place of the old command-line syntax from the 1980s:

```
bsdtar -x -m -f file.zip --exclude __MACOSX --exclude '__MACOSX/*'
```

## Further reading

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/239578/18044
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/288568/18044
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/307886/18044

Comment: AFAICT, those `__MACOSX` are meant to store macOS specific metadata. Shouldn't we want to restore those metadata when uncompressing on macOS rather than discard them?